# Handling the data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, puppeteer

In the code below I am looping through urls and scraping the data (title and content) from each url.
My goal is to add this data later on to another page so I need to reach the data based on the title, content and url.

I want something like this
for example:

```
    `myData = [{url:"www.blabla.com",
               title:"bla",
               content:"bla bla bla..." },
               {url: ...`
```

and then I want to reach the data like:

```
    `myData[0].url`
```

```
async function myFunction(){
  values = await main();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    (async () => {
      let myUrl = values[i];
      let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      let page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(myUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
      let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let title = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;
        let content = document.querySelector('div.o-article').innerText;
        return {
          title,
          content,
        };
      });

    })();
}
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: use queryselectorall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build the `myData` array as you go:

```js
const myData = [];

async function myFunction () {
  const values = await main();
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const myUrl = values[i];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(myUrl, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const title = document.querySelector('h1').innerText;
      const content = document.querySelector('div.o-article').innerText;
      return {
        title,
        content,
      };
    });
    
    // add data to array
    myData.push({
      url: myUrl,
      title: data.title,
      content: data.content
    })
  }
}
```

And you don't want to do an async IFFE when you're already inside an async function:

```js
async function myFunction(){
  for (/* ... */) {

    // don't do this:
    (async () => {
      /* ... */
    })();

  }
}
```